# #1072 - Key column 'department' doesn't exist in table insql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I tried to create table, I am getting the error.

> Key column 'department' doesn't exist in table in sql.
>   FOREIGN KEY(department) REFERENCES department(d_no) error is this line

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
e_no INTEGER,
e_name VARCHAR(25),
city VARCHAR(25),
age INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(department) REFERENCES department(d_no)
);
```

Comment: The error message is correct - your table contains no key `department`. Even though it's a foreign key, it skill needs to be in the `employee` table.

Comment: then how to write sir

Comment: There's nothing special about it -- you just need to include it in the table. Like `age INTEGER, department INTEGER` -- the `department` datatype simply needs to match the datatype on the secondary table. Also, the `department` would need to be the primary key in your second table.

Comment: department INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(department) REFERENCES department(d_no)
);

Comment: Can't create table `ema`.`employee` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" this error displayed  ema mean database name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
CREATE TABLE department (
    d_no INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    d_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE employee(
    e_no INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    e_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(25),
    age INTEGER NOT NULL,
    department INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(department) REFERENCES department(d_no)
);
```